# how custom the edit form or add form in a subgrid from jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

Where can i custom edit form or add form in a subgrid ?
If i want custom the edit form from grid i do:

```
$.extend($.jgrid.edit, {
    recreateForm: true,
    onInitializeForm: function($form) {
    //CHANGE ASPECT IN EDIT FORM
        $('<tr class="FormData"><td class="CaptionTD ui-widget-content" colspan="6">' +
           '<div style="padding:3px" class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">' +
           '<b>INFORMATIONS GENERALES</b></div></td></tr>')
           .insertBefore('#tr_pers_genre_id');
}
```

but where for the subgrid ?

Here parts of grid and subgrid code

```
dbbxll.jqGrid({
        url: "db_bxll_jqgrid.php?q=2",
        editurl: "db_bxll_data.php",
        datatype: "xml",
        mtype: "GET",
        pager: "#pagerdbbxll",
        //autowidth: true,
        width: 1200,
        height: 600,
        rowNum: 25,
        rowList: [25, 75, 250],
        sortname: "pers_date_inscription",
        sortorder: "desc",
        forceFit: true, 
        shrinkToFit:true, 
        viewrecords: true,
        gridview: true,
        autoencode: true,
        toppager: true,
        idPrefix: "m",
        caption: "db be",

//GROUPING EXAMPLE
        grouping:false,
        groupingView : {
            groupField : ['pers_genre_id'],
            groupColumnShow : [true],
            groupText : ['<b>{0}</b>'],
            // AFFICHE LE NBRE DE LIGNES DANS CHAQUE GROUPE groupText : ['<b>{0} - {1} Item(s)</b>'],
            groupCollapse : true,
            groupOrder: ['asc']         
        },

// PRINCIPAL GRID COLUMN DEFINITION
        colNames: ["ID","DATE INSCR","DATE REACT","PROVENANCE","GENRE","NUM INSCR","NOM","PRENOM","DATE NAISS","NATIONALITE","NUM IDNATIONAL","NUM IBIS","ADRESSE","N°","BTE","CP","VILLE","GSM","TEL","MAIL","TYPE PERMIS","ETUDE","LIEU ETUDE","DATE INOCC","INOCC","STATUT","CPRO1","CPRO2","CPRO3"],
        colModel: [
....
],// end colModel principal grid

subGrid : true,
        subGridRowExpanded: function(subgrid_id, row_id) {

            var subgrid_table_id, pager_id;
            subgrid_table_id = subgrid_id+"_t";
            pager_id = "p_"+subgrid_table_id;

            var subgrid_table_id9, pager_id9;
            subgrid_table_id9 = subgrid_id+"_t9";
            pager_id9 = "p9_"+subgrid_table_id9;

            // CUT THE idPrefix
            var mainGridPrefix = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "idPrefix");
            pureRowId = $.jgrid.stripPref(mainGridPrefix, row_id);

            $("#"+subgrid_id).html("<table id='"+subgrid_table_id+"' class='scroll'></table><div id='"+pager_id+"' class='scroll'></div><table id='"+subgrid_table_id9+"' class='scroll'></table><div id='"+pager_id9+"' class='scroll'></div>");

// SUIVIS - ENTRETIEN SUBGRID DETAIL
            jQuery("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid({
            hiddengrid:true,
            width: 1100,
            height: 300,
            url:"entretien_subgrid.php?q=2&id="+pureRowId,
            datatype: "xml",
            mtype: 'GET',
            pager: '#entretienpagerdetail',
            rowNum:50,
            rowList:[5,10,20,30,40,50],
            rownumbers: true,
            viewrecords: true,
            pager: pager_id,
            idPrefix: "s" + row_id + "_",
            caption:"SUIVIS",
            ondblClickRow: function (rowid, iRow, iCol, e) {e.stopPropagation();},
            colNames:['ENT_ID','ID','DATE ENTRETIEN','PROJET','CONSEILLER','COMMENTAIRE'],
            colModel:[
],

subGrid: true,
            subGridRowExpanded: function (subgrid_id2, row_id2) {

                // SUBGRID ACTIONS
                var subgrid_table_id2, pager_id2;
                subgrid_table_id2 = subgrid_id2+"_t2";
                pager_id2 = "p2_"+subgrid_table_id2;

                // SUBGRID ER
                var subgrid_table_id3, pager_id3;
                subgrid_table_id3 = subgrid_id2+"_t3";
                pager_id3 = "p2_"+subgrid_table_id3;

                // SUBGRID RESULTAT
                var subgrid_table_id4, pager_id4;
                subgrid_table_id4 = subgrid_id2+"_t4";
                pager_id4 = "p2_"+subgrid_table_id4;

                // CUT IDPREFIX
                var mainGridPrefix = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "idPrefix");
                pureRowId2 = $.jgrid.stripPref(mainGridPrefix, row_id2);

                $("#"+subgrid_id2).html("<table id='"+subgrid_table_id2+"' class='scroll'></table><div id='"+pager_id2+"' class='scroll'></div><table id='"+subgrid_table_id3+"' class='scroll'></table><div id='"+pager_id3+"' class='scroll'></div><table id='"+subgrid_table_id4+"' class='scroll'></table><div id='"+pager_id4+"' class='scroll'></div>");

//SUBGRID ACTIONS I've 3 subrids I show completely one
                jQuery("#"+subgrid_table_id2).jqGrid({
...
}); // END SUBGRID ACTION

...

//SUBGRID RESULTAT
                jQuery("#"+subgrid_table_id4).jqGrid({
                hiddengrid: true,
                width: 1000,
                height: 150,
                url:"resultat_subgrid.php?q=3&ent_id="+pureRowId2,
                datatype: "xml",
                mtype: 'GET',
                pager: '#resultatpagerdetail',
                rowNum:50,
                rowList:[5,10,20,30,40,50],
                rownumbers: true,
                viewrecords: true,
                pager: pager_id4,
                caption:"RESULTATS",
                ondblClickRow: function (rowid, iRow, iCol, e) {e.stopPropagation();},
                colNames:['RES_ID','DATE RESULTAT','RESULTAT','COMMENTAIRE','ENT_ID'],
                colModel:[
...
],
}); // END SUBGRID

// NAVGRID RESULTAT
                jQuery("#"+subgrid_table_id4).jqGrid('navGrid',"#"+pager_id4,{edit:true,add:true,del:true},

                    {//prmEdit 
                    //reloadAfterSubmit:false,
                    closeAfterEdit:true,
                    bSubmit: "Modifier",
                    width:400,
                    onclickSubmit: function(fordid) {
                    var mygrid = $("#"+subgrid_table_id4);
                    var did = mygrid.jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');
                    var celdid = mygrid.jqGrid('getCell', did, 'res_id');
                    if (did != null) {
                        jQuery("#"+subgrid_table_id4).setGridParam({editurl:'resultat_updatedel.php?q=3&res_id='+celdid});
                        //alert(celdid);
                            }
                        else alert("Vous n'avez sélectionné aucun projet")
                        },
                    //refresh:true
                    },//end edit

                    {//prmAdd
                    closeAfterAdd:true,
                    bSubmit: "Sauvegarder",
                    width:400,
                    //reloadAfterSubmit:true,
                    beforeShowForm: function(formid) {
                        // we should get the id of the first subgrid here : subgrid_table_id
                        var mid = jQuery("#"+subgrid_table_id).getGridParam('selrow');
                        pureRowId = $.jgrid.stripPref(mainGridPrefix, mid);
                        if (mid != null ) {
                        // now we can set it in addurl
                        jQuery("#"+subgrid_table_id4).setGridParam({editurl:'resultat_add.php?q=3&ent_id=0'+pureRowId});
                            }
                        else alert("Vous n'avez sélectionné aucun projet")
                        }
                    },//end add

                    {//prmDel
                    closeAfterDel:true,
                    //reloadAfterSubmit:false,
                    onclickSubmit: function(fordid) {
                    var mygrid = $("#"+subgrid_table_id4);
                    var did = mygrid.jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');
                    var celdid = mygrid.jqGrid('getCell', did, 'res_id');
                    if (did != null) {
                        jQuery("#"+subgrid_table_id4).setGridParam({editurl:'resultat_updatedel.php?q=3&res_id='+celdid});
                        //alert(celdid);
                            }
                        else alert("Vous n'avez sélectionné aucun projet")
                        },
                    }//end del
                );//end navgrid resultat

                }, // end subgridrowexpanded
```

well the file is too long but i can put it fully.
thanks for all

Comment: Where is the code of grid and subgrids?

Comment: i edit the code... but the file is too long... if you want i put all code ;)

Comment: I can put an onInitializeForm in the navGrid from a subgid but I must put the same one for addform and one for edit form... how to do this more economic ?

Comment: sorry, but I don't understand the problem which you have. You can define `var myInitializeForm = function ($form) {...};` and use `onInitializeForm: myInitializeForm` for both Add and Edit options. If you use my fork of jqGrid: [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) then you can use jqGrid option `formEditing: {onInitializeForm: ...}` (see [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/New-style-of-usage-options-of-internal-methods)). By the way I suppose that `beforeShowForm` should be used instead of `onInitializeForm`.

Comment: Thank you. In fact, I just wanted to change the EditForm and AddForm from a subgrid ... and as I change the EditForm and AddForm the main grid through .extend $ ($. Jgrid.edit, {...I thought there was a way to do the same. I'm using the 4.6.0 version of jqgrid, In this regard, it's really really great.
I will do as you say. In fact I have another outstanding issue in a button I added in a AddForm ... if you have the opportunity to guide me on the problem ... In any case thank you for all that information  very useful every time.

Comment: You are welcome! If you have additional problems you should just describe there in details or even better to provide the demo which demonstrates the problem and which uses non-minimized code of jqGrid.

Comment: ok thanks again... I'll do my best.